# Rust fabric pattern, storing multiple factories in hashmap

Tags: design-patterns, rust, factory-pattern

I want to be able to store multiple factories in a single hashmap in order to add them to it later (by plugins for example) and then get each one by key-name in application (this is a resource manager).

The problem is in generic of Fabric trait, fabrics can create fruits of different types but I need to specify something in here `HashMap<String, Box<dyn Fabric>>`, for example `HashMap<String, Box<Fabric<Apple>>>` or `HashMap<String, Box<Fabric<T>>>` which is also not wery useful because as I said we can create really different fruits.

Also I guess there might be a problem in foo method, about borrowing content.

So how would you implement this "the rust way"?

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait Fruit {
    fn get_name(&self) -> String;
}

trait Fabric<T: Fruit> {
    fn build(&self) -> Box<T>;
}

struct Banana {}
impl Fruit for Banana {
    fn get_name(&self) -> String { String::from("I'm banana") }
}

struct BananaFabric {}
impl Fabric<Banana> for BananaFabric  {
    fn build(&self) -> Box<Banana> {
        Box::new(Banana {})
    }
}

struct Apple {}
impl Fruit for Apple {
    fn get_name(&self) -> String { String::from("I'm apple") }
}

struct AppleFabric {}
impl Fabric<Apple> for AppleFabric  {
    fn build(&self) -> Box<Apple> {
        Box::new(Apple {})
    }
}

struct C {
    map: HashMap<String, Box<dyn Fabric>>,
}

impl C {
    pub fn new() -> C {
        C {
            map: HashMap::new()
        }
    }

    pub fn foo(&self, key: String) {
        match self.map.get(&key) {
            Some(&fabric) => {
                let fruit = fabric.build();
                println!("{}", fruit.get_name())
            },
            _ => println!("No fabric found")
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c = C::new();
    c.foo(String::from("bar"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two options:

**Dynamic dispatch (trait objects)**:

```
trait Fabric {
  fn build(&self) -> Box<dyn Fruit>;
}

[...]

impl Fabric for BananaFabric  {
  fn build(&self) -> Box<dyn Fruit> {
    Box::new(Banana {})
  }
}
```

**Using an `enum`**:

```
enum Fruits {
  Banana, 
  Apple
}
impl Fruit for Fruits {
  fn get_name(&self) -> String { 
    match self {
      Banana => String::from("I'm banana"),
      Apple => String::from("I'm apple"),
      _ => String::from("")
    }
  }
}

[...]

impl Fabric for BananaFabric  {
  fn build(&self) -> Box<Fruits> {
    Box::new(Fruits::Banana)
  }
}
```

In both cases the `foo` method will look like:

```
pub fn foo(&self, key: String) {
  match self.map.get(&key) {
    Some(fabric) => {
      let fruit = fabric.build();
        println!("{}", fruit.get_name())
      },
      _ => println!("No fabric found")
  }
}
```

Comment: I really like the first solution, works like a charm! For those who interested and want to check by yourself, my final code is here - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a6f108c51ad1247ff8d9ee0231a1f27a

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait A {
    fn boo(&self) -> i32;
}

struct B {}

impl A for B {
    fn boo(&self) -> i32 {
        15
    }
}

struct C {
    map: HashMap<String, Box<dyn A>>,
}

impl C {
    pub fn new() -> C {
        C {
            map: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn foo(&self, key: String) {
        match self.map.get(&key) {
            Some(val) => println!("{}", val.boo()),
            _ => println!("None"),
        }
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut c = C::new();

    c.map.insert(String::from("bar"), Box::new(B{}));

    c.foo(String::from("bar"));
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f9d6d9ff94eb8714ef6a6d0ab023fe84

BTW. it's `Factory Design Pattern`.

Comment: Changed a code example to better describe my problem. I hope it's more clean now.
I want to have hashmap of fabrics actually.

Comment: Removing the reference from pattern matching solves copy problem, but I still don't know what to write in hashmap type declaration.